# JavaScript loop through JSON array?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to loop through the following json array:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "msg": "hi",
  "tid": "2013-05-05 23:35",
  "fromWho": "hello1@email.se"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "msg": "there",
  "tid": "2013-05-05 23:45",
  "fromWho": "hello2@email.se"
}
```

And have tried the following

```
for (var key in data) {
   if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(data[key].id);
   }
}
```

But for some reason I'm only getting the first part, id 1 values.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there some missing brackets ? It doesn't really look like an array, now. And did you parse the JSON ?

Comment: is it an array of objects? (are you missing [] or they are not there?)

Comment: It's neither JSON nor array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Please change the title, this is to iterate through a JSON object properties, not an array

Answer (score 306):

Your JSON should look like this:

```
let json = [{
    "id" : "1", 
    "msg"   : "hi",
    "tid" : "2013-05-05 23:35",
    "fromWho": "hello1@email.se"
},
{
    "id" : "2", 
    "msg"   : "there",
    "tid" : "2013-05-05 23:45",
    "fromWho": "hello2@email.se"
}];
```

You can loop over the Array   like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    let obj = json[i];

    console.log(obj.id);
}
```

Or like this (suggested from Eric) be careful with IE support

```
json.forEach(function(obj) { console.log(obj.id); });
```

Comment: Or more concisely, `json.forEach(function(obj) { console.log(obj.id); });`

Comment: Unless on IE8 (as usual, everyone but IE ;) )

Comment: I think that example can be confuse, because var json is not a JSON object, but an array. In this case, .forEach works well, but when you use a json object, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 40):

There's a few problems in your code, first your json must look like :

```
var json = [{
"id" : "1", 
"msg"   : "hi",
"tid" : "2013-05-05 23:35",
"fromWho": "hello1@email.se"
},
{
"id" : "2", 
"msg"   : "there",
"tid" : "2013-05-05 23:45",
"fromWho": "hello2@email.se"
}];
```

Next, you can iterate like this :

```
for (var key in json) {
if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  alert(json[key].id);
  alert(json[key].msg);
}
}
```

And it gives perfect result.

See the fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/zrSmp/

Answer (score 36):

try this

```
var json = [{
    "id" : "1", 
    "msg"   : "hi",
    "tid" : "2013-05-05 23:35",
    "fromWho": "hello1@email.se"
},
{
    "id" : "2", 
    "msg"   : "there",
    "tid" : "2013-05-05 23:45",
    "fromWho": "hello2@email.se"
}];

json.forEach((item) => {
  console.log('ID: ' + item.id);
  console.log('MSG: ' + item.msg);
  console.log('TID: ' + item.tid);
  console.log('FROMWHO: ' + item.fromWho);
});
```

Answer (score 19):

```
var arr = [
  {
  "id": "1",
  "msg": "hi",
  "tid": "2013-05-05 23:35",
  "fromWho": "hello1@email.se"
  }, {
  "id": "2",
  "msg": "there",
  "tid": "2013-05-05 23:45",
  "fromWho": "hello2@email.se"
  }
];
```

**forEach method for easy implementation.**

```
arr.forEach(function(item){
  console.log('ID: ' + item.id);
  console.log('MSG: ' + item.msg);
  console.log('TID: ' + item.tid);
  console.log('FROMWHO: ' + item.fromWho);
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Since i already started looking into it:

```
var data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "msg": "hi",
    "tid": "2013-05-05 23:35",
    "fromWho": "hello1@email.se"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "msg": "there",
    "tid": "2013-05-05 23:45",
    "fromWho": "hello2@email.se"
}]
```

And this function

```
var iterateData =function(data){   for (var key in data) {
       if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          console.log(data[key].id);
       }
    }};
```

You can call it like this

```
iterateData(data); // write 1 and 2 to the console
```

### Update after Erics comment

As [eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102441/eric) pointed out [a `for in` loop for an array can have unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea). The referenced question has a lengthy discussion about pros and cons.

### Test with for(var i ...

But it seems that the follwing is quite save:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1)
```

Although a test in chrome had the following result

```
var ar = [];
ar[0] = "a"; 
ar[1] = "b";
ar[4] = "c";

function forInArray(ar){ 
     for(var i = 0; i < ar.length; i += 1) 
        console.log(ar[i]);
}

// calling the function
// returns a,b, undefined, undefined, c, undefined
forInArray(ar);
```

#### Test with `.forEach()`

At least in chrome 30 this works as expected

```
var logAr = function(element, index, array) {
    console.log("a[" + index + "] = " + element);
}
ar.forEach(logAr); // returns a[0] = a, a[1] = b, a[4] = c
```

#### Links

- [see `for in` at the mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)
- the new [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method
- [a comment that states that array comprehension makes `for in` less bad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#note_on_use_with_arrays)
- [Array comprehension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Array_comprehensions_%28Merge_into_Array_comprehensions%29) introduced with javascript 1.7 in firefox 2 (yes 2)

Comment: **-1** - `for ... in ` loops should not be used for arrays

Comment: Array comprehensions use `for each`. `for ... in ...` is a language construct for enumerating object keys in an arbitrary order. That is not the right construct for an array.

Answer (score 10):

It is working. I just added square brackets to JSON data. The data is:

```
var data = [
    { 
        "id": "1",
        "msg": "hi", 
        "tid": "2013-05-05 23:35", 
        "fromWho": "hello1@email.se" 
    }, 
    { 
        "id": "2", 
        "msg": "there", 
        "tid": "2013-05-05 23:45", 
        "fromWho": "hello2@email.se"
    }
]
```

And the loop is:

```
for (var key in data) {
   if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         alert(data[key].id);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Your data snippet need to be expanded a little, and it has to be this way to be proper JSON. Notice I just include the array name attribute `item`.

```json
{
  "item": [{
    "id": "1",
    "msg": "hi",
    "tid": "2013-05-05 23:35",
    "fromWho": "hello1@email.se"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "msg": "there",
    "tid": "2013-05-05 23:45",
    "fromWho": "hello2@email.se"
  }]
}
```

Your JavaScript is simply

```js
var objCount = json.item.length;
for (var x = 0; x < objCount; x++) {
  var curitem = json.item[x];
}
```

Comment: FYI, there's a typo I think. The `xx++` should be `x++`

Answer (score 7):

It must be an array if you want to iterate over it. You're very likely missing `[` and `]`.

```
var x = [{
    "id": "1",
        "msg": "hi",
        "tid": "2013-05-05 23:35",
        "fromWho": "hello1@email.se"
}, {
    "id": "2",
        "msg": "there",
        "tid": "2013-05-05 23:45",
        "fromWho": "hello2@email.se"
}];

var $output = $('#output');
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    console.log(x[i].id);
}
```

Check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lpiepiora/kN7yZ/

Answer (score 6):

A bit late but i hope i may help others :D

your json needs to look like something Niklas already said. And then here you go:

```
for(var key in currentObject){
        if(currentObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          console.info(key + ': ' + currentObject[key]);
        }
   }
```

if you have an Multidimensional array, this is your code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < multiDimensionalArray.length; i++) {
    var currentObject = multiDimensionalArray[i]
    for(var key in currentObject){
            if(currentObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              console.info(key + ': ' + currentObject[key]);
            }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, all I can see there is that you have two JSON objects, seperated by a comma. If both of them were inside an array (`[...]`) it would make more sense.

And, if they ARE inside of an array, then you would just be using the standard "for var i = 0..." type of loop. As it is, I think it's going to try to retrieve the "id" property of the string "1", then "id" of "hi", and so on.

Answer (score 5):

the very easy way!

```
var tire_price_data = JSON.parse('[{"qty":"250.0000","price":"0.390000"},{"qty":"500.0000","price":"0.340000"},{"qty":"1000.0000","price":"0.290000"}]'); 
tire_price_data.forEach(function(obj){
    console.log(obj);
    console.log(obj.qty);
    console.log(obj.price);
})
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
var json = {
    "persons": [
        {"name": "Lili", "age": 23, "is_student": true},
        {"name": "James", "age": 24, "is_student": true},
        {"name": "John", "age": 25, "is_student": false}
    ]
};

for (var key in json.persons) {
    for (var keyName in json.persons[key]) {
        alert(keyName + ': ' + (json.persons[key])[keyName]);
    }
}
```

//Output: name:Lili, age:23, is_student:true, ...

Answer (score 2):

A short solution using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "1",
  "msg": "hi",
  "tid": "2013-05-05 23:35",
  "fromWho": "hello1@email.se"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "msg": "there",
  "tid": "2013-05-05 23:45",
  "fromWho": "hello2@email.se"
}];
data.map((item, i) => console.log('Index:', i, 'Id:', item.id));
```

And to cover the cases when the property `"id"` is not present use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "1",
  "msg": "hi",
  "tid": "2013-05-05 23:35",
  "fromWho": "hello1@email.se"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "msg": "there",
  "tid": "2013-05-05 23:45",
  "fromWho": "hello2@email.se"
}, {
  "msg": "abcde",
  "tid": "2013-06-06 23:46",
  "fromWho": "hello3@email.se"
}];

data.filter(item=>item.hasOwnProperty('id'))
                .map((item, i) => console.log('Index:', i, 'Id:', item.id));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for-loop then to get the values you can De-structure them

```
const arr = [
        {
            id:123,
            desc:"do something",
            isDone:false
        },
        {
            id:124,
            desc:"do something",
            isDone:true
        }
    ]

for(let _i in arr){
    let {id, desc, isDone} = arr[_i]
    // do something
    console.log({id, desc, isDone});
}
```