# ibm worklight stored procedure

Tags: json, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to parse this `json` object in `javascript` and have to obtain the values of key pass in string format.

```
{
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "resultSet": [
      {
         "name": "a",
         "pass": "123",
         "time_stamp": "2014-04-07T10:13:17.000Z"
      },
      {
         "name": "chetan",
         "pass": "123456",
         "time_stamp": "2014-04-07T10:13:34.000Z"
      },
      {
         "name": "dileep",
         "pass": "456321",
         "time_stamp": "2014-04-07T10:13:54.000Z"
      },
      {
         "name": "bnc",
         "pass": "654321",
         "time_stamp": "2014-04-07T10:19:37.000Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: what did you try and what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking in a general sense (no links to Worklight) I would look at other answers:

[How do I iterate over a JSON structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078118/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-json-structure)

[JavaScript loop through json array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238173/javascript-loop-through-json-array)

[How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object)

In Worklight, if your example is the response of a Worklight adapter, the response will be in a property called `invocationResult`.

See also https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/handling_backend_responses_in_adapters?lang=en

Comment: actually im getting this json from invoking the sqladapter from which i want to obtain the all values of the pass in string form in the java script

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are missing. What is the issue exactly?