# IBM Worklight - How to parse adapter response?

Tags: javascript, json, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC()
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME;
END//
```

This is my unction to call stored procedure using SQL adapter:

```
function callStored() {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure({
        procedure : "proc",
        parameters : []
    });
}
```

This is the invocationResult:

```
{
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "resultSet": [
      {
         "name": "a",
         "pass": "123",
         "time_stamp": "2014-04-07T10:13:17.000Z"
      },
      {
         "name": "chetan",
         "pass": "123456",
         "time_stamp": "2014-04-07T10:13:34.000Z"
      },
      {
         "name": "dileep",
         "pass": "456321",
         "time_stamp": "2014-04-07T10:13:54.000Z"
      },
      {
         "name": "bnc",
         "pass": "654321",
         "time_stamp": "2014-04-07T10:19:37.000Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to parse this and display or alert the values of `name`, `pass` and `time_stamp`.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your application JavaScript (common\js\main.js), you can have something like the following. In the below code an alert will be displayed with the values of the `name` key from the resultSet.

You can also take a look here: [use resultset returned by WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement within sql adapter procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744628/use-resultset-returned-by-wl-server-invokesqlstatement-within-sql-adapter-proced)

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    invokeAdapter();
}

function invokeAdapter() {
    var invocationData = {
        adapter: "your-adapter-name",
        procedure: "callStored",
        parameters: []
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure (invocationData, {
        onSuccess: invocationSuccess,
        onFailure: invocationFailure}
    );
}

function invocationSuccess(response) {
    var i,
        resultSet = response.invocationResult.resultSet;
        namesArray = [];

    for (i = 0; i < resultSet.length; i++) {
        namesArray[i] = resultSet[i].name;
    }
    alert (JSON.stringify(namesArray));
}

function invocationFailure(response) {
   alert (response);
}
```

You have already asked this here: [ibm worklight stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935212/ibm-worklight-stored-procedure/22935546)
Why did you not follow through the documentation and learned how to write the above?

Please read the documentation!

Comment: A simple way to interact with the 'invocationResult' using JQuery, which is embedded by default in WL hybrid apps:

var nn = new Array(), pp = new Array(), tt = new Array();
$(response.invocationResult.resultSet).each(function(idx, data){
nn[idx] = data.name;
pp[idx] = data.pass;
tt[idx] = data.time_stamp;
});
console.log(nn);
console.log(pp);
console.log(tt);

Answer (score 0):

Please read the "[Invoking adapter procedures from client applications](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/04_06_Invoking_adapter_procedures_from_client_applications.pdf)" and its [Exercise and code sample](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/InvokingAdapterProceduresProject.zip) in the [Getting started with IBM Worklight](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html) page.

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    getUsersInfo();
}

function getUsersInfo(){
    var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'YOUR_ADAPTER',
        procedure : 'YOUR_PROCEDURE',
        parameters : []
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
        onSuccess : getUsersInfoSuccess,
        onFailure : getUsersInfoFailure
    });
}

function getUsersInfoSuccess(result){
    if (result.invocationResult.Items.length > 0) {
        displayUsersInfo(result.invocationResult.Items);
    } else { 
        getUsersInfoFailure();
    }
}

function getUsersInfoFailure(result){
    alert("Cannot retrieve users info");
}

function displayUsersInfo(items){
    var i = 0, usersInfo = '';
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        usersInfo += ' name: ' + items[i].name;
        usersInfo += ' pass: ' + items[i].pass;
        usersInfo += ' time_stamp: ' + items[i].time_stamp;
    }
    alert(usersInfo);
}
```

Comment: can i write this function in httpadapter.js file and write wl.server.invokeProcedure() insted of wl.client

Comment: @user3510619, no you cannot - please read the training module as it explains exactly what you're asking. You are confusing between client-side and server-side.