# how to store JSON data into key-value pairs in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, web

how to store JSON data into key-value pairs in javascript?

I have a json data file : data.js
It contains follwing data

```
[
    { "Sound": "0.550951615" },
    { "Battery": 0.2567320563 },
    { "Screen": 0.0703125 },
    { "RAM": 0.1246117102 },
    { "Connectivity": 0 },
    { "Camera": 0.2721623766 },
    { "Design": 0.3677622768 },
    { "Processor": 0 }
]
```

how to store this data in key-value pair data-structure in java script?

Comment: It's almost like it was made for it, JSON being JavaScript Object Notation and all ?

Comment: It's already key:value.

Comment: actually I hv a json file , I want to access each data field in that  json,,,how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.map` or `Array.reduce` (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) to map the Array elements to an object, something like:

```js
var objmap = {}, objred = {};
// parse the string (from your file)
var objFromFile =
  JSON.parse('[\
      { "Sound": "0.550951615" },\
      { "Battery": 0.2567320563 },\
      { "Screen": 0.0703125 },\
      { "RAM": 0.1246117102 },\
      { "Connectivity": 0 },\
      { "Camera": 0.2721623766 },\
      { "Design": 0.3677622768 },\
      { "Processor": 0 }\
  ]');
// and map it to [obj]
var mapped = objFromFile.map( 
                function (v) { for (var l in v) {this[l] = v[l];} }, 
                objmap
             );
// or use reduce if you prefer it
var reduced = objFromFile.reduce( 
                 function(p, n) { 
                   for (var l in n) {p[l] = n[l];} 
                   return p;
                 },
                 objred
              );

// show the result, using JSON.stringify
document.querySelector('#result').textContent = 
  'mapped:\n' + JSON.stringify(objmap, null, ' ') +
  '\n\nreduced:\n' +  JSON.stringify(objred, null, ' ');
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: If I saw an `Array.map` in a section of code I'd still be expecting an array of values back - `Array.reduce` would be cleaner (using the second parameter).

Comment: @Digigizmo: have you actually tried using `reduce`?

Answer (score 1):

JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation. This is a systematic Syntax to store data.

for storing single value:

```
var Object1 = {
  "Key": "Value"
}
```

for storing multiple value:

```
var Object1 = {
  "Key1": "Value1",
  "Key2": "Value2",
  "Key3": "Value3",
  "nth key": "nth value"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to process your data structure to get this done.

```
var a = [
    { "Sound": "0.550951615" },
    { "Battery": 0.2567320563 },
    { "Screen": 0.0703125 },
    { "RAM": 0.1246117102 },
    { "Connectivity": 0 },
    { "Camera": 0.2721623766 },
    { "Design": 0.3677622768 },
    { "Processor": 0 }
]
var keyValue = {}
a.forEach(function(e) {
    keyValue[Object.keys(e)[0]] = Object.values(e)[0]
})
```

Output of `console.log(keyValue)`

```
{"Sound":"0.550951615","Battery":0.2567320563,"Screen":0.0703125,"RAM":0.1246117102,"Connectivity":0,"Camera":0.2721623766,"Design":0.3677622768,"Processor":0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObject = { 
 key: value,
 key: value
 };
```

You would literally just list your contents in that format.

Other Resources: 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

[How to "properly" create a custom object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You're already storing the data as key:value.

If you're wondering how you can access the various bits and pieces of your data, checkout this article: [JavaScript loop through json array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238173/javascript-loop-through-json-array)

OR ...

You can find a particular k:v pair by index. In your case, if you store the payload in a variable, you could access the data like so:

```
var data = [
    { "Sound": "0.550951615" },
    { "Battery": 0.2567320563 },
    { "Screen": 0.0703125 },
    { "RAM": 0.1246117102 },
    { "Connectivity": 0 },
    { "Camera": 0.2721623766 },
    { "Design": 0.3677622768 },
    { "Processor": 0 }
]

data[0]
```

This would return { "Sound": "0.550951615" }

There are a TON of resources that you can search for JSON references.

Good Luck!

Comment: thanks, actualy I want to access each filed in the json data ,hw to do that?

Comment: The link I mentioned in the answer has several examples of how to loop through the array of data ... I'm not quite sure if I understand what you're asking for, if that post doesn't answer your question.