# How to get share count from Mail.ru?

Tags: jquery, json, share

I try to get share count from Mail.ru social network ([Мой Мир](https://my.mail.ru)).

If I go to browser, put this URL `http://connect.mail.ru/share_count?url_list=THIS_MY_URL&callback=1&func=?` and press enter, I'll get this response:

```
?(
{
  "THIS_MY_URL":{"shares":10,"clicks":5}
});
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
var url = encodeURIComponent(location.href);

$.getJSON('http://connect.mail.ru/share_count?url_list=' + url + '&callback=1&func=?', function(response) {
  alert(response[url].shares);
});
```

In Chrome console I get this message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shares' of undefined
```

Whats wrong? How to make it work?

Help me please!

Comment: Can you show the json data you are receiving in response.Is there shares property ?

Comment: For example, URL in query is http://vk.com — JSON data is: ``?({ "http:\/\/vk.com": {"shares":12372, "clicks":413} });``

Comment: This is not valid json as per http://jsonlint.com/ .It shows {
    "http://vk.com": {
        "shares": 12372,
        "clicks": 413
    }
}

Comment: Look this link please: https://github.com/sapegin/social-likes/blob/master/src/social-likes.js#L61-L69 They parse (or something else) this not valid JSON to share count. How to do this on my code (at first message)?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked solution I [found here](https://github.com/enjoyiacm/goodshare.js/blob/master/goodshare.js#L340-L356).

**First**. Error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shares' of undefined` showen, when response Object is empty. This is standard response from social network, when URL have not share count, i.e. `Object = {}`.

For fix it, put this code in `$.getJSON()` (from my first post):

```
if ($.isEmptyObject(response)) alert('0'); // If Object = {}
else // Code for not empty Object
```

**Second**. For show counter for URL with `shares > 0` (or `clicks > 0`), use this code:

```
var url = encodeURIComponent(location.href);
for (var url in response) {
    if (response.hasOwnProperty(url)) {
        var count = response[url].shares;
        break;
    }
}

alert(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

See here I am getting the value.

```
    var data = { "vk.com": { "shares": 12372, "clicks": 413} };

        for (var url in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty('vk.com')) {
                var shares= data['vk.com'].shares;
            }
        }
```

[image: Debugging Poster]

Comment: OK. This work to ONE url. But If I don't know what url to be in link? For example, url is ``encodeURIComponent(location.href)`` — then this code don't work.

Comment: Can you show me then a real json data with multiple case.

Comment: also look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238173/javascript-loop-through-json-array

Comment: Hmm.. jQuery Code in my first (start) message — how to get your code to them?

Comment: Maybe need parse not valid JSON response (for ex. ``?({ "http:\/\/vk.com": {"shares":12372, "clicks":413} });`` or any) to valid and next try to ``for(...)`` from your code? How?