# How to format a JSON string as a table using jq?

Tags: json, bash, jq

Just started out with Bash scripting and stumbled upon jq to work with JSON.

I need to transform a JSON string like below to a table for output in the terminal.

```
[{
    "name": "George",
    "id": 12,
    "email": "george@domain.example"
}, {
    "name": "Jack",
    "id": 18,
    "email": "jack@domain.example"
}, {
    "name": "Joe",
    "id": 19,
    "email": "joe@domain.example"
}]
```

What I want to display in the terminal:

```
ID        Name
=================
12        George
18        Jack
19        Joe
```

Notice how I don't want to display the email property for each row, so the jq command should involve some filtering. The following gives me a plain list of names and id's:

```
list=$(echo "$data" | jq -r '.[] | .name, .id')
printf "$list"
```

The problem with that is, I cannot display it like a table. I know jq has some formatting options, but not nearly as good as the options I have when using `printf`. I think I want to get these values in an array which I can then loop through myself to do the formatting...? The things I tried give me varying results, but never what I really want.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you add some sample output of your `jq -r ...` command?

Comment: Your use of `echo` can be avoided `jq -r '...' <<<$data` or `jr -r '...' < input-file.json`.

Comment: Is your question: I have a string `"name1 value1 name2 value2 name3 value3"` how can I print it as a table?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Why not something like:

```
echo '[{
    "name": "George",
    "id": 12,
    "email": "george@domain.example"
}, {
    "name": "Jack",
    "id": 18,
    "email": "jack@domain.example"
}, {
    "name": "Joe",
    "id": 19,
    "email": "joe@domain.example"
}]' | jq -r '.[] | "\(.id)\t\(.name)"'
```

Output

```
12  George
18  Jack
19  Joe
```

---

**Edit 1 :** For fine grained formatting use tools like `awk`

```
 echo '[{
    "name": "George",
    "id": 12,
    "email": "george@domain.example"
}, {
    "name": "Jack",
    "id": 18,
    "email": "jack@domain.example"
}, {
    "name": "Joe",
    "id": 19,
    "email": "joe@domain.example"
}]' | jq -r '.[] | [.id, .name] | @csv' | awk -v FS="," 'BEGIN{print "ID\tName";print "============"}{printf "%s\t%s%s",$1,$2,ORS}'
ID  Name
============
12  "George"
18  "Jack"
19  "Joe"
```

---

**Edit 2 :** In reply to

> There's no way I can get a variable containing an array straight
> from jq?

Why not?

A bit involved example( in fact modified from yours ) where email is changed to an array demonstrates this

```
echo '[{
    "name": "George",
    "id": 20,
    "email": [ "george@domain1.example" , "george@domain2.example" ]
}, {
    "name": "Jack",
    "id": 18,
    "email": [ "jack@domain3.example" , "jack@domain5.example" ]
}, {
    "name": "Joe",
    "id": 19,
    "email": [ "joe@domain.example" ]
}]' | jq -r '.[] | .email'
```

**Output**

```
[
  "george@domain1.example",
  "george@domain2.example"
]
[
  "jack@domain3.example",
  "jack@domain5.example"
]
[
  "joe@domain.example"
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works very good in this particular case, the id's have all the same length. Imagine I'd switch the order the fields, that would give me something that doesn't look like a handy table at all. I really am looking for a solution I could use on more datasets. Thanks for your answer, though!

Comment: Ok, got it. There's no way I can get a variable containing an array straight from jq? I always have to go from a string?

Comment: Thanks for your help, the output is exactly as I wanted (except for the quotes around the names). It felt strange to go from a string instead of getting a ready to use array like we would in for example Python. To me it feels clumsy and dirt, but I guess it's just me that has to get used to the ideas of bash?

I'll try to make this into a function I can reuse, so I can use this for more JSON strings with different headers.

Comment: @Rein : for fine-grained formatting you need print the output in the csv format and then use `awk`, but mind that complicated cases may fail.  For your second comment see the last edit and read it together with [\[ this \]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18238241/1620779) answer.

Comment: The `jq` array should not be confused with [\[ bash arrays \]](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html) which is an entirely different thing. In fact what you might need is bash [\[ wrapper \]](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/wrapper.html) over jq. But I'm doubtful it will  be any good except for a few test cases considering the myriad of jsons that you've to parse.

Comment: Thank you for diving deep into my question. Actually the question is answered already, but I'd still like to figure this out a bit more. After your edit it seems possible to get arrays from jq, for example for "email", but it's not possible to get associative arrays from jq, right? Ideally I would like to get a bash array from it, representing the JSON string. Just like you would do in any other language eg: `myarray = json_encode(myjsonstring)`. If this isn't possible, how exactly do people use jq then? I imagine they want to loop over the data at some point?

Comment: @Rein If I'm not mistaken, there is no associative array in json as far as I could infer from this [\[ page \]](http://json.org/). Or I may be wrong with the terminology. :\ . A `json object` resembles a `bash` associative array though. In fact [\[ this \]](http://xmeblog.blogspot.in/2015/02/transforming-json-object-into.html) post shows how to convert an json array to bash array. What is demonstrated there are customized bash wrappers to achieve certain objectives..

Answer (score 179):

Using the `@tsv` filter has much to recommend it, mainly because it handles numerous "edge cases" in a standard way:

```
.[] | [.id, .name] | @tsv
```

Adding the headers can be done like so:

```
jq -r '["ID","NAME"], ["--","------"], (.[] | [.id, .name]) | @tsv'
```

The result:

```
ID  NAME
--  ------
12  George
18  Jack
19  Joe
```

As pointed out by @Tobia, you might want to format the table for viewing by using `column` to post-process the result produced by jq. If you are using a bash-like shell then `column -ts $'\t'` should be quite portable.

### `length*"-"`

To automate the production of the line of dashes:

```
jq -r '(["ID","NAME"] | (., map(length*"-"))), (.[] | [.id, .name]) | @tsv'
```

Comment: The @tsv filter is even on the basic filters manual page for jq, hmm... I wonder what else I might have missed :)

Comment: I would like to add a standard Linux utility `column` that you can use to format TSV into pretty lists. You can use it like this: `jq -r '... | @tsv' | column -nts$'\t'` or you can save it as an alias in .bashrc `alias tsvtable="column -nts\$'\\t'"` and use it like `... | tsvtable`

Answer (score 44):

Defining headers by hand is suboptimal! Omitting headers is also suboptimal.

TL;DR

#### data

```
[{ "name": "George", "id": 12, "email": "george@domain.example" },
{ "name": "Jack", "id": 18, "email": "jack@domain.example" },
{ "name": "Joe", "id": 19, "email": "joe@domain.example" }]
```

#### script

```
  [.[]| with_entries( .key |= ascii_downcase ) ]
      |    (.[0] |keys_unsorted | @tsv)
         , (.[]  |map(.) |@tsv)
```

#### how to run

```
$ < data jq -rf script  | column -t
name    id  email
George  12  george@domain.example
Jack    18  jack@domain.example
Joe     19  joe@domain.example
```

I found this question while summarizng some data from amazon web services. The problem I was working on, in case you want another example:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-spot-instance-requests | tee /tmp/ins |
    jq  --raw-output '
                                     # extract instances as a flat list.
    [.SpotInstanceRequests | .[]
                                     # remove unwanted data
    | {
        State,
        statusCode: .Status.Code,
        type: .LaunchSpecification.InstanceType,
        blockPrice: .ActualBlockHourlyPrice,
        created: .CreateTime,
        SpotInstanceRequestId}
    ]
                                        # lowercase keys
                                        # (for predictable sorting, optional)
    |  [.[]| with_entries( .key |= ascii_downcase ) ]
        |    (.[0] |keys_unsorted | @tsv)               # print headers
           , (.[]|.|map(.) |@tsv)                       # print table
    ' | column -t
```

Output:

```
state      statuscode                   type     blockprice  created                   spotinstancerequestid
closed     instance-terminated-by-user  t3.nano  0.002000    2019-02-24T15:21:36.000Z  sir-r5bh7skq
cancelled  bad-parameters               t3.nano  0.002000    2019-02-24T14:51:47.000Z  sir-1k9s5h3m
closed     instance-terminated-by-user  t3.nano  0.002000    2019-02-24T14:55:26.000Z  sir-43x16b6n
cancelled  bad-parameters               t3.nano  0.002000    2019-02-24T14:29:23.000Z  sir-2jsh5brn
active     fulfilled                    t3.nano  0.002000    2019-02-24T15:37:26.000Z  sir-z1e9591m
cancelled  bad-parameters               t3.nano  0.002000    2019-02-24T14:33:42.000Z  sir-n7c15y5p
```

Input:

```
$ cat /tmp/ins
{
    "SpotInstanceRequests": [
        {
            "Status": {
                "Message": "2019-02-24T15:29:38+0000 : 2019-02-24T15:29:38+0000 : Spot Instance terminated due to user-initiated termination.",
                "Code": "instance-terminated-by-user",
                "UpdateTime": "2019-02-24T15:31:03.000Z"
            },
            "ActualBlockHourlyPrice": "0.002000",
            "ValidUntil": "2019-03-03T15:21:36.000Z",
            "InstanceInterruptionBehavior": "terminate",
            "Tags": [],
            "InstanceId": "i-0414083bef5e91d94",
            "BlockDurationMinutes": 60,
            "SpotInstanceRequestId": "sir-r5bh7skq",
            "State": "closed",
            "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX",
            "LaunchedAvailabilityZone": "eu-north-1a",
            "LaunchSpecification": {
                "Placement": {
                    "Tenancy": "default",
                    "AvailabilityZone": "eu-north-1a"
                },
                "ImageId": "ami-6d27a913",
                "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                    {
                        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                        "VirtualName": "root",
                        "NoDevice": "",
                        "Ebs": {
                            "Encrypted": false,
                            "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                            "VolumeType": "gp2",
                            "VolumeSize": 8
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "EbsOptimized": false,
                "SecurityGroups": [
                    {
                        "GroupName": "default"
                    }
                ],
                "Monitoring": {
                    "Enabled": false
                },
                "InstanceType": "t3.nano",
                "AddressingType": "public",
                "NetworkInterfaces": [
                    {
                        "DeviceIndex": 0,
                        "Description": "eth-zero",
                        "NetworkInterfaceId": "",
                        "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                        "SubnetId": "subnet-420ffc2b",
                        "AssociatePublicIpAddress": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Type": "one-time",
            "CreateTime": "2019-02-24T15:21:36.000Z",
            "SpotPrice": "0.008000"
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "Message": "Your Spot request failed due to bad parameters.",
                "Code": "bad-parameters",
                "UpdateTime": "2019-02-24T14:51:48.000Z"
            },
            "ActualBlockHourlyPrice": "0.002000",
            "ValidUntil": "2019-03-03T14:51:47.000Z",
            "InstanceInterruptionBehavior": "terminate",
            "Tags": [],
            "Fault": {
                "Message": "Invalid device name /dev/sda",
                "Code": "InvalidBlockDeviceMapping"
            },
            "BlockDurationMinutes": 60,
            "SpotInstanceRequestId": "sir-1k9s5h3m",
            "State": "cancelled",
            "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX",
            "LaunchedAvailabilityZone": "eu-north-1a",
            "LaunchSpecification": {
                "Placement": {
                    "Tenancy": "default",
                    "AvailabilityZone": "eu-north-1a"
                },
                "ImageId": "ami-6d27a913",
                "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                    {
                        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda",
                        "VirtualName": "root",
                        "NoDevice": "",
                        "Ebs": {
                            "Encrypted": false,
                            "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                            "VolumeType": "gp2",
                            "VolumeSize": 8
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "EbsOptimized": false,
                "SecurityGroups": [
                    {
                        "GroupName": "default"
                    }
                ],
                "Monitoring": {
                    "Enabled": false
                },
                "InstanceType": "t3.nano",
                "AddressingType": "public",
                "NetworkInterfaces": [
                    {
                        "DeviceIndex": 0,
                        "Description": "eth-zero",
                        "NetworkInterfaceId": "",
                        "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                        "SubnetId": "subnet-420ffc2b",
                        "AssociatePublicIpAddress": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Type": "one-time",
            "CreateTime": "2019-02-24T14:51:47.000Z",
            "SpotPrice": "0.011600"
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "Message": "2019-02-24T15:02:17+0000 : 2019-02-24T15:02:17+0000 : Spot Instance terminated due to user-initiated termination.",
                "Code": "instance-terminated-by-user",
                "UpdateTime": "2019-02-24T15:03:34.000Z"
            },
            "ActualBlockHourlyPrice": "0.002000",
            "ValidUntil": "2019-03-03T14:55:26.000Z",
            "InstanceInterruptionBehavior": "terminate",
            "Tags": [],
            "InstanceId": "i-010442ac3cc85ec08",
            "BlockDurationMinutes": 60,
            "SpotInstanceRequestId": "sir-43x16b6n",
            "State": "closed",
            "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX",
            "LaunchedAvailabilityZone": "eu-north-1a",
            "LaunchSpecification": {
                "Placement": {
                    "Tenancy": "default",
                    "AvailabilityZone": "eu-north-1a"
                },
                "ImageId": "ami-6d27a913",
                "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                    {
                        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                        "VirtualName": "root",
                        "NoDevice": "",
                        "Ebs": {
                            "Encrypted": false,
                            "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                            "VolumeType": "gp2",
                            "VolumeSize": 8
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "EbsOptimized": false,
                "SecurityGroups": [
                    {
                        "GroupName": "default"
                    }
                ],
                "Monitoring": {
                    "Enabled": false
                },
                "InstanceType": "t3.nano",
                "AddressingType": "public",
                "NetworkInterfaces": [
                    {
                        "DeviceIndex": 0,
                        "Description": "eth-zero",
                        "NetworkInterfaceId": "",
                        "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                        "SubnetId": "subnet-420ffc2b",
                        "AssociatePublicIpAddress": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Type": "one-time",
            "CreateTime": "2019-02-24T14:55:26.000Z",
            "SpotPrice": "0.011600"
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "Message": "Your Spot request failed due to bad parameters.",
                "Code": "bad-parameters",
                "UpdateTime": "2019-02-24T14:29:24.000Z"
            },
            "ActualBlockHourlyPrice": "0.002000",
            "ValidUntil": "2019-03-03T14:29:23.000Z",
            "InstanceInterruptionBehavior": "terminate",
            "Tags": [],
            "Fault": {
                "Message": "Addressing type must be 'public'",
                "Code": "InvalidParameterCombination"
            },
            "BlockDurationMinutes": 60,
            "SpotInstanceRequestId": "sir-2jsh5brn",
            "State": "cancelled",
            "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX",
            "LaunchedAvailabilityZone": "eu-north-1a",
            "LaunchSpecification": {
                "Placement": {
                    "Tenancy": "default",
                    "AvailabilityZone": "eu-north-1a"
                },
                "ImageId": "ami-6d27a913",
                "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                    {
                        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda",
                        "VirtualName": "root",
                        "NoDevice": "",
                        "Ebs": {
                            "Encrypted": false,
                            "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                            "VolumeType": "gp2",
                            "VolumeSize": 8
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "EbsOptimized": false,
                "SecurityGroups": [
                    {
                        "GroupName": "default"
                    }
                ],
                "Monitoring": {
                    "Enabled": false
                },
                "InstanceType": "t3.nano",
                "AddressingType": "",
                "NetworkInterfaces": [
                    {
                        "DeviceIndex": 0,
                        "Description": "eth-zero",
                        "NetworkInterfaceId": "",
                        "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                        "SubnetId": "subnet-420ffc2b",
                        "AssociatePublicIpAddress": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Type": "one-time",
            "CreateTime": "2019-02-24T14:29:23.000Z",
            "SpotPrice": "0.011600"
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "Message": "Your spot request is fulfilled.",
                "Code": "fulfilled",
                "UpdateTime": "2019-02-24T15:37:28.000Z"
            },
            "ActualBlockHourlyPrice": "0.002000",
            "ValidUntil": "2019-03-03T15:37:26.000Z",
            "InstanceInterruptionBehavior": "terminate",
            "Tags": [],
            "InstanceId": "i-0a29e9de6d59d433f",
            "BlockDurationMinutes": 60,
            "SpotInstanceRequestId": "sir-z1e9591m",
            "State": "active",
            "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX",
            "LaunchedAvailabilityZone": "eu-north-1a",
            "LaunchSpecification": {
                "Placement": {
                    "Tenancy": "default",
                    "AvailabilityZone": "eu-north-1a"
                },
                "ImageId": "ami-6d27a913",
                "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                    {
                        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                        "VirtualName": "root",
                        "NoDevice": "",
                        "Ebs": {
                            "Encrypted": false,
                            "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                            "VolumeType": "gp2",
                            "VolumeSize": 8
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "EbsOptimized": false,
                "SecurityGroups": [
                    {
                        "GroupName": "default"
                    }
                ],
                "Monitoring": {
                    "Enabled": false
                },
                "InstanceType": "t3.nano",
                "AddressingType": "public",
                "NetworkInterfaces": [
                    {
                        "DeviceIndex": 0,
                        "Description": "eth-zero",
                        "NetworkInterfaceId": "",
                        "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                        "SubnetId": "subnet-420ffc2b",
                        "AssociatePublicIpAddress": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Type": "one-time",
            "CreateTime": "2019-02-24T15:37:26.000Z",
            "SpotPrice": "0.008000"
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "Message": "Your Spot request failed due to bad parameters.",
                "Code": "bad-parameters",
                "UpdateTime": "2019-02-24T14:33:43.000Z"
            },
            "ActualBlockHourlyPrice": "0.002000",
            "ValidUntil": "2019-03-03T14:33:42.000Z",
            "InstanceInterruptionBehavior": "terminate",
            "Tags": [],
            "Fault": {
                "Message": "Invalid device name /dev/sda",
                "Code": "InvalidBlockDeviceMapping"
            },
            "BlockDurationMinutes": 60,
            "SpotInstanceRequestId": "sir-n7c15y5p",
            "State": "cancelled",
            "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX",
            "LaunchedAvailabilityZone": "eu-north-1a",
            "LaunchSpecification": {
                "Placement": {
                    "Tenancy": "default",
                    "AvailabilityZone": "eu-north-1a"
                },
                "ImageId": "ami-6d27a913",
                "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                    {
                        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda",
                        "VirtualName": "root",
                        "NoDevice": "",
                        "Ebs": {
                            "Encrypted": false,
                            "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                            "VolumeType": "gp2",
                            "VolumeSize": 8
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "EbsOptimized": false,
                "SecurityGroups": [
                    {
                        "GroupName": "default"
                    }
                ],
                "Monitoring": {
                    "Enabled": false
                },
                "InstanceType": "t3.nano",
                "AddressingType": "public",
                "NetworkInterfaces": [
                    {
                        "DeviceIndex": 0,
                        "Description": "eth-zero",
                        "NetworkInterfaceId": "",
                        "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                        "SubnetId": "subnet-420ffc2b",
                        "AssociatePublicIpAddress": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Type": "one-time",
            "CreateTime": "2019-02-24T14:33:42.000Z",
            "SpotPrice": "0.011600"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `column -t` made the trick to align the headers with the table itself. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `column -ts $'\t'` to split on tab characters but not spaces -- otherwise values with spaces will be split into multiple columns. From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57235/140650

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller what's up with the mostly pointless edit? is it site-policy to "improve" other people's posts now days or are you just obsessing over some imaginary standard? what was the motivation for your edit?

Comment: It is site policy to edit posts to improve them.  I've been doing lots of edits on posts that don't use approved example domains.  See this thread on meta about it:  [What is the purpose of modifying the example domain in data example?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418905/what-is-the-purpose-of-modifying-the-example-domain-in-data-example)

Comment: I noticed the following problems with your version (as of 2021-03-26): **1:** the available column headers are only derived from the first object's key .... **2:** if a later object is missing a key, its table cells are shifted into the wrong column ... **3:** it fails as soon as it encounters an array value.

Comment: @Abdull My answer is not trying to solve _your problem_ 5 years before you had it, but rather the problem in the original question. If the input data is not uniform, you will of course have to massage it, or put in "-" or "n/a" into values that are null in the original data, otherwise you won't get a neat table. 3rd point: none of the other solution address this either. Post a new question with your requirements and surely someone will be happy to give you tips or a whole solution. Anyway, the key point remains: You can't change the requirements five years later and call the outcome a problem.

Comment: instead of "problem", I should have used "caveat".... but: Please don't take other users' edits and comments as a threat. And my comment makes explicit which requirements/constraints are required for your solution to work.

Answer (score 21):

The problem with the answers above is they only work if the fields are all about the same width.

To avoid this issue, the Linux `column` command could be used:

```json
// input.json
[
  {
    "name": "George",
    "id": "a very very long field",
    "email": "george@domain.example"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jack",
    "id": 18,
    "email": "jack@domain.example"
  },
  {
    "name": "Joe",
    "id": 19,
    "email": "joe@domain.example"
  }
]
```

Then:

```
▶ jq -r '.[] | [.id, .name] | @tsv' input.json | column -ts $'\t'
a very very long field  George
18                      Jack
19                      Joe
```

Answer (score 7):

I made a mix with all responses to get all this behaviours

- create header table
- handle long fields
- create a function to reuse

**function bash**

```
function jsonArrayToTable(){
     jq -r '(.[0] | ([keys[] | .] |(., map(length*"-")))), (.[] | ([keys[] as $k | .[$k]])) | @tsv' | column -t -s $'\t'   
}
```

**Sample use**

```
echo '[{"key1":"V1.1", "key2":"V2.1"}, {"keyA":"V1.2", "key2":"V2.2"}]' | jsonArrayToTable
```

**output**

```
key1  key2
----  ----
V1.1  V2.1
V2.2  V1.2
```

Comment: I noticed th following problems with your version (as of 2021-03-26): **1:** the available column headers are only derived from the *first object's key* .... **2:**: if a later object is *missing a key*, its table cells are shifted into the wrong column ... **3:**: it fails as soon as it encounters an *array* value.

Answer (score 2):

Generic oneliner that works with any *JSON array of objects* (`[{..}, {..}, ...]`) on *stdin*:

```
jq -r 'map( with_entries(  .value |= tostring  ) ) | (map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @tsv' | column -ts $'\t'
```

(inspired by [*How to Convert from JSON to CSV at The Command Line*](https://earthly.dev/blog/convert-to-from-json/#convert-json-to-csv-via-the-command-line-using-jq)).

It is robust enough to handle the following corner cases:

- array values are fine
- objects with missing keys are fine
- identifies all keys (== table columns) from all objects (== table rows) (no requirement for the first object to contain all keys)
- keys can appear in arbitrary order within the object
- handles space (e.g. strings with spaces) gracefully without incorrectly misplacing cells in the wrong column as the separator is a tab character

  - therefore may need additional escaping if tab characters are part of the input

### Examples:

Here document:

```
cat <<'EOF' | jq -r 'map( with_entries(  .value |= tostring  ) ) | (map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @tsv' | column -ts $'\t'
[
  { "id": 12, "email": "george@domain.example" },
  { "fullname": "Jack Foo", "id": 18, "email": "jack@domain.example" },
  { "fullname": "Joe Bar Baz", "email": "joe@domain.example", "list": [554, "hello world", "another string"] },
  { "list": [], "id": 949, "fullname": "" },
  { "zzz": 35.4 }
]
EOF

## output:
# email                  fullname     id   list                                  zzz
# george@domain.example               12                                         
# jack@domain.example    Jack Foo     18                                         
# joe@domain.example     Joe Bar Baz       [554,"hello world","another string"]  
#                                     949  []                                    
#                                                                                35.4
```

`ip route` (leveraging the `-j` JSON format option):

```
ip -j route | jq -r 'map( with_entries(  .value |= tostring  ) ) | (map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @tsv' | column -ts $'\t'

## sample output:
# dev     dst          flags  gateway   metric  prefsrc    protocol  scope
# enp0s3  default      []     10.0.2.2  1024    10.0.2.15  dhcp      
# enp0s3  10.0.2.0/24  []                       10.0.2.15  kernel    link
# enp0s3  10.0.2.2     []               1024    10.0.2.15  dhcp      link
# lxcbr0  10.0.3.0/24  []                       10.0.3.1   kernel    link
```

Comment: Note: if the input is a separate JSON object per line (ndjson) then add `-s` argument to `jq` so that it 'slurps' all inputs into an array first.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate an *HTML* table instead of a table for terminal output:

```bash
echo '[{
    "name": "George",
    "id": 12,
    "email": "george@domain.example"
}, {
    "name": "Jack",
    "id": 18,
    "email": "jack@domain.example"
}, {
    "name": "Joe",
    "id": 19,
    "email": "joe@domain.example"
}]' | jq -r 'map("<tr><td>" + .name + "</td><td>" + (.id | tostring) + "</td></tr>") | ["<table>"] + . + ["</table>"] | .[]'
```

Output:

```html
<table>
<tr><td>George</td><td>12</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jack</td><td>18</td></tr>
<tr><td>Joe</td><td>19</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

More simple implement:

```
jq -r '(.[0]|keys_unsorted|(.,map(length*"-"))),.[]|map(.)|@tsv'|column -ts $'\t'
```

you can add the following jq function into `~/.jq`:

```
def pretty_table:
 (.[0]|keys_unsorted|(.,map(length*"-"))),.[]|map(.)|@tsv
 ;
```

and then run:

```
cat apps.json | jq -r pretty_table | column -ts $'\t'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values don't contain spaces, this might be helpful:

```
read -r -a data <<<'name1 value1 name2 value2'

echo "name value"
echo "=========="

for ((i=0; i<${#data[@]}; i+=2)); do
  echo ${data[$i]} ${data[$((i+1))]}
done
```

**Output**

```
name value
==========
name1 value1
name2 value2
```

Comment: I'm beginning to realise I can't get an array straight from jq, is that correct? So the way to go is to get a string from it (in a workable format) and go from there?