# Need jq help to turn a semi-malformed but very simple json file into csv

Tags: json, csv, tensorflow, key, jq

I have a bit of a problem. I've tried so many different iterations of `jq -r` against a large set of json files being spit out by an object detector but I just can't make it happy enough to give me a csv file. I simplified these massive files into a very short example below with the exact same data structure (note, the names of things like "book", "person", "animal" are ever changing among the scripts, so if there is a way to do this without hardcoding the keys in the command, that would be most desirous but not requiredous)

Example:

```
{
    "/src/files/image_1.png": {
        "book": 0.01711445301771164,
        "person": 0.000330559065533263624,
        "place": 0.9814764857292175,
        "animal": 1.8662762158783153e-05,
        "vehicle": 0.0010597968939691782
    },
    "/src/files/image_2.png": {
        "book": 0.23741412162780762,
        "person": 0.1587823033328247,
        "place": 0.59659236669504,
        "animal": 0.0036556862760335207,
        "vehicle": 0.003555471543222666
    }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to make a csv file whose tabular format would look something like this:

| File | Book | Person | Place | Animal | Vehicle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /src/files/image_1.png | 0.01711445301771164 | 0.000330559065533263624 | 0.9814764857292175 | 1.8662762158783153e-05 | 0.0010597968939691782 |
| /src/files/image_2.png | 0.23741412162780762 | 0.1587823033328247 | 0.59659236669504 | 0.0036556862760335207 | 0.003555471543222666 |

Comment: How is that JSON *semi-malformed*?

Comment: This example isn't a good example of what I was talking about--I suppose this is a case in which I gave too much information about the problems in my files which distracted from the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
. as $data |
keys_unsorted as $ids |
( .[ $ids[0] ] | keys_unsorted ) as $fields |
(
   [ "id", $fields[] ],
   ( $ids[] | [ ., $data[.][$fields[]] ] )
) | @csv
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/zF5h5xsJF0)

or

```
keys_unsorted as $ids |
( .[ $ids[0] ] | keys_unsorted ) as $fields |
(
   [ "id", $fields[] ],
   ( to_entries[] | [ .key, .value[$fields[]] ] )
) | @csv
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/f_pi5E6SAV)

Neither handles an empty input (`{}`) well.

---

For comparison, @peak's solution with headers would be

```
keys_unsorted as $ids |
( .[ $ids[0] ] | keys_unsorted ) as $fields |
(
   [ "id", $fields[] ],
   ( $ids[] as $id | [ $id, .[$id][$fields[]] ] )
) | @csv
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/YDFSulx_hy)

It doesn't handle an empty input (`{}`) well either

Comment: I didn't realize you didn't want to hard-code the field names. Fixed.

Comment: Excellent! Your examples worked perfectly. I will need to read up a bit more on why this works, but I appreciate your help in it.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is a bit trickier than it might otherwise be because it is "data-driven" (no key names other than "File" are hard-coded in the jq program) while not assuming that the inner keys are ordered consistently:

```
  keys_unsorted as $outer
  | (.[$outer[0]] | keys_unsorted) as $inner
  | ["File"] + ($inner|map((.[:1]|ascii_upcase) + .[1:])),
    ($outer[] as $k
     | [$k] + [.[$k] | .[$inner[]]])
  | @tsv
```

You might of course wish to use `@csv` instead of `@tsv`.

(There are many SO questions illustrating how headers can be added, e.g. the following includes an illustration of how to add them without hardcoding them, and with dynamically generated "-" lines beneath the primary headers: [How to format a JSON string as a table using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139107/how-to-format-a-json-string-as-a-table-using-jq))

Comment: A table with "randomly"-ordered columns is not to useful without a header row.

Comment: This did indeed work far better than my efforts, but ikegami's was a full solution. I will need to do a fair bit of reading to reach a point where I can script as well as you.

Comment: @DavidMoore - Since you want a complete solution, it is now provided, including capitalization of the header names.