# How convert JSON to TSV in bash

Tags: node.js, csv, curl, jq

I am trying to convert JSON file from the command below to CSV format:

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.coinex.com/v1/market/kline?market=BCHBTC&type=1min' -H "Accept: application/json"
```

I tried jq command as following, but it was unsuccessful :

```
jq '.data |to_entries[] | @csv'
```

OR

```
jq '.data |to_entries[] | [.key,  (.0|tonumber),(.1|tonumber),(.2|tonumber),(.3|tonumber),(.4|tonumber),(.5|tonumber),(.6|tonumber),(.7|tonumber)   )] | @csv'
```

desired output is like:

```
            1619094720  0.01738857  0.01742868  0.01742868  0.01737360  1.24151689  0.0215974650849251  BCHBTC
            1619094780  0.01742823  0.01742913  0.01742913  0.01742807  0.89060000  0.0155215977170000  BCHBTC
            1619094840  0.01744941  0.01745423  0.01745423  0.01744941  0.42820000  0.0074724290140000  BCHBTC
            1619094900  0.01745458  0.01740857  0.01745458  0.01740857  0.73530000  0.0128245470890000  BCHBTC
```

Comment: That is not CSV, are you looking for tab-separated output?. Is `jq -r '.data[] | @tsv'` what you are looking for?

Comment: 'jq -r '.data[] | @tsv' ' solved the problem, thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JSON string as a table using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139107/how-to-format-a-json-string-as-a-table-using-jq)

Comment: yes its answered  the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jq -r '.data[] | @tsv` ' solved the problem, thanks @
Inian

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146472/what-is-the-best-way-to-increase-my-reputation-and-privileges) enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `to_entries`, just apply the filter directly to the arrays, e.g.:

```
jq -r '.data[] | .[0:-1] | map(tonumber) | @tsv'
```

Note that the above removes the `"BCHBTC"` text field, as noted by *peak* in the comments this can be included with the special or operator (`//`):

```
jq -r '.data[] | tonumber? // . | @tsv'
```

Comment: why take the slice?

Comment: @peak: otherwise `tonumber` complains, anyway the removed text-field can easily be made redundant

Comment: Given OP has confirmed wanting to keep the text field, you could use `tonumber? // .`

Comment: @peak: Nice I didn't know you could use the `//` operator like this. I have included your suggestion

Comment: You would still need `map` though if using @tsv, it makes little practical difference.