# jq not processing a JSON file in Cygwin

Tags: json, cygwin, jq

When I try to use jq in cygwin to process a json file, I always get the message

```
assertion "cb == jq_util_input_next_input_cb" failed: file "/usr/src/ports/jq/jq-1.6-1.x86_64/src/jq-1.6/src/util.c", line 371, function: jq_util_input_get_position
```

I've seen some other posts on this but I don't seem to find the solution. Is there any way to get it to work?

I'm using jq 1.6 in cygwin.

**Update:**

This is my JSON file:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "firstName": "firstName_1",
      "lastName": "lastName_1",
      "phoneNumber": "111111111",
      "emailAddress": "emailAddress_1@email.com"
    },
    {
      "userId": 2,
      "firstName": "firstName_2",
      "lastName": "lastName_2",
      "phoneNumber": "222222222",
      "emailAddress": "emailAddress_2@email.com"
    },
    {
      "userId": 3,
      "firstName": "firstName_3",
      "lastName": "lastName_3",
      "phoneNumber": "333333333",
      "emailAddress": "emailAddress_3@email.com"
    },
    {
      "userId": 4,
      "firstName": "firstName_4",
      "lastName": "lastName_4",
      "phoneNumber": "444444444",
      "emailAddress": "emailAddress_4@email.com"
    },
    {
      "userId": 5,
      "firstName": "firstName_5",
      "lastName": "lastName_5",
      "phoneNumber": "555555555",
      "emailAddress": "emailAddress_5@email.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I use this:

```
echo "$(<file_1.json)" | jq -r '["ID","NAME"], ["--","------"], (.users[] | .userId, .lastName)'
```

I get this:

```
[
  "ID",
  "NAME"
]
[
  "--",
  "------"
]
1
lastName_1
2
lastName_2
3
lastName_3
4
lastName_4
5
lastName_5
```

If I try this:

```
echo "$(<file_1.json)" | jq -r '["ID","NAME"], ["--","------"], (.users[] | .userId, .lastName) | @tsv'
```

I get this:

```
ID      NAME
--      ------
assertion "cb == jq_util_input_next_input_cb" failed: file "/usr/src/ports/jq/jq-1.6-1.x86_64/src/jq-1.6/src/util.c", line 371, function: jq_util_input_get_position
                    Aborted (core dumped)
```

I was basing on this link:
[How to format a JSON string as a table using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139107/how-to-format-a-json-string-as-a-table-using-jq)

Comment: a bit more details, like command line, data examples ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing the array brackets around `.userId, .lastName` (which are also present in the solution you have linked to).

```
["ID","NAME"], ["--","------"], (.users[] | [.userId, .lastName]) | @tsv
```

```
ID  NAME
--  ------
1   lastName_1
2   lastName_2
3   lastName_3
4   lastName_4
5   lastName_5
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Oz_l9qKtus)