# Add up numerical values of entry in json and store in variable as string

Tags: json

I have a JSON file that is being generated from an API and stored into a variable `myJson` that looks like this:

```
    {
    "results": [
        {
          "term": "A",
          "count": 1569
        },
        {
          "term": "B",
          "count": 1375
        },
        {
          "term": "C",
          "count": 1372
        }
    ]
    }
```

Is there any approach to add up all of the numerical values in the "count" entry and store it as a string into a variable?

So: `stringVariable = 1569 + 1375 + 1372`

Note: This is just a small snippet of a giant JSON file so I believe will need a formula of some sort.

Thanks!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? The community won't help you if you expect us to solve everything

Comment: JSON is a data format, not a programming language. It does not have methods.

Comment: @DanLowe I assume s/he means method in the sense of "approach"

Comment: Is it just a straight forward solution in which you just need to traverse through the list, pickup the results(index).count and sum it up ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript loop through json array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238173/javascript-loop-through-json-array)

Comment: Maybe you could use a "loop".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what language you're asking about, let's use JavaScript.

```
function add(data) {
    let sum = 0;
    data['results'].slice(1).forEach( obj =>
        sum += obj['count']
    );
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: the only issue i have is that this function is returning `1569 + 1375 + 1372` instead of the sum

Comment: that is why when you declare your stringVariable , makes it as int type int stringVariable ...

Comment: Sorry, the question made it look like you wanted the string. I'll edit my answer to provide the actual sum.