# Iterate JSON give characters, not elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using .getJSON to pull in data to graph.  For some reason when I try to loop through the JSON array it gives me each individual character like it's not seeing it as an array, yet when I dump data to console it's properly formatted JSON.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $.getJSON("/getgraphdata", function(result) {
      console.log(result.length);                                                                
      testFunction(result);
  });
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <script>
 function testFunction(data) {
     console.log(data); // line 16
     //console.log(data.length); Gives total character count. 
     for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         var obj = data[i];

         //console.log(obj.id);
     }
 }


 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is the data directly from console. ( from line 16 )

```
[{"id":"1375857","temperature":"78.98","humidity":"90.2","nodeName":"Bsmt_Front","timestamp":"1536424185"},{"id":"1375856","temperature":"78.98","humidity":"77.1","nodeName":"Bsmt_Back","timestamp":"1536424185"},{"id":"1375855","temperature":"77.54","humidity":"49.9","nodeName":"Living_Room","timestamp":"1536424180"},{"id":"1375854","temperature":"0","humidity":"0","nodeName":"Bsmt_Room","timestamp":"1536424179"},{"id":"1375853","temperature":"79.52","humidity":"82.7","nodeName":"Flow_Tent","timestamp":"1536424158"}]
```

I used the highest rated answer here   [JavaScript loop through json array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238173/javascript-loop-through-json-array)

If I comment out line 21 it shows undefined.  If I do a console.log(obj) it iterates through every single character in the array.

Everything points to it not seeing that as an array, but the [] are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `data` contains a json string instead of an array. As described above you can use `JSON.parse` to parse it. But it looks like your API response has an invalid content type and that's why `getJSON` don't parse response by itself.

Comment: Thank you.  The api wasn't returning correctly encoded information, even though it looked right.  Once that was fixed the parse statement was not needed.

Comment: Oh. So I wasn't 100% correct saying about content type. Could you please describe invalid encoding more detailed? I'm curious about what exactly was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

you can use JSON.parse to parse string into javascript object

so inside your `testFunction` you should do

`data = JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: That works.  Why is that needed though when it's already in JSON format?

Comment: it seems from the problem that data is in string format and hence you have to parse it

Comment: As [Oleksandr has already written](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52237309/402037). jQuery will automatically parse the response if the returned content type indicates that the response is JSON. If jQuery doesn't parse the response, then you're sending the wrong content type.