# how to loop json string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I return data from PHP Like that.

```
$return['fillable'] = [
    'field_one',
    'field_two',
    'field_three',
    'field_four',
    'field_five',
];

$json = json_encode($return);

return $json;
```

Now in my ajax response, I want to loop fillable array.

```
$.ajax({
    'type': "GET",
    'global': false,
    'dataType': 'json',
    'url': "/commission-process/"+$('#token').val(),
    'data': {'ajax': true},
    'success': function (data) {

        // how to loop my return array data.

    }
});
```

My Question is that, I want to loop fillable array which prints like that.

```
field_one
field_two
field_three
field_four
field_five
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to loop it inside of javascript or php?

Comment: `data.fillable` will contain your array and you can loop over it like you loop over any array in javascript.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra The json will already be parsed by jQuery when you use `'dataType': 'json'`.

Comment: In side JavaScript.

Comment: @JohnBrad Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238173/javascript-loop-through-json-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I didn't know whether you wanted to loop through it in PHP or Javascript, here's a result in both.

**PHP:**
You have to first decode the json like this:

```
$array = json_decode( $json, true );
```

Then you can loop through it like through any other array.

**Javascript:**

```
for(i = 0; i<data.fillable.length; i++)
{
    console.log(data.fillable[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. : )

Comment: @JohnBrad No problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
'type': "GET",
'global': false,
'dataType': 'json',
'url': "/commission-process/"+$('#token').val(),
'data': {'ajax': true},
'success': function (data) {

    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(json, function(i,e){
       console.log(i);
       console.log(e);
    });
}
```

});