# Delay inside a JavaScript foreach loop that doing API call

Tags: javascript, velo

I have a script that fetch stocks symbols from the data base and doing API calls to get stock price.
After 30 iteration, the script failed, it seems like there is a rate limit on the Stocks API server so I want to add dealy between the iterations in order to find the best frequency.
This is my script:

```
const apiQueue = [];
    const newPrices = {};

    table.items.forEach(stock =>
    {
       // console.log(stock.symbol)
        apiQueue.push(getJSON(console.log(`https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock/real-time-price/AAPL`)).then(json =>
        {
            newPrices[json.symbol] = json.price;
        }));
    });

    await Promise.all(apiQueue);

   table.items.forEach(stock =>
    {
        stock.change = (newPrices[stock.symbol] - stock.price) / stock.price * 100;
        stock.price = newPrices[stock.symbol];
    });
```

I'm new in JavaScript, I tried everything, and I can't make it work.
My limit right now is 30 API calls, can I divide the foreach loop and send 30 calls every few seconds?.

***Update***

Thank you guys, i tried what you told me to do but i can't get it work.
that's my last test:

```
fetch('https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock/real-time-price/aapl,wpm,bhf')
  .then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(data => {
    // Work with JSON data here
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(data);

    console.log(myJSON)
 for(var i = 0; i < myJSON.length; i++) {
    var obj = myJSON[i];

    console.log(obj.symbol);
}

  })
```

I tried all the examples on this post [JavaScript loop through json array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238173/javascript-loop-through-json-array)
non of them work.

Comment: Could you not just wrap your call into setTimeout? - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Instead of doing 30 calls, why don't you get [everything](https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock/real-time-price/) and filter with what you want? That would just take 1 call.

Comment: @FF in addition, it's possible the API has a filtering option already, so you can just request all items matching criteria (e.g., by ID or whatever that value is). Not sure if this API has it but it's a possibility in general.

Comment: @VLAZ in fact, after reading the documentation on that API, technically it doesn't expose the method for multiple values, but it does handle it OK. I just tried it like [this](https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock/real-time-price/CYCN,DWSH,MARA), which goes to show how OP didn't even tried to read the [documentation](https://financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs) in an extensive manner.

Comment: @FF- so a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) then. All that's really needed is to get all the IDs of the elements, make them comma separated and append them to the URL. Then you make one request.