# How to loop through json response in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, loops, object

Note: I have already gone through stackoverflow [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object) but without any luck.

I have following json response received in ajax. I am trying to loop through it but still no success.

```
[
{"id":"1","type":"size","value":"large","datetime":"2020-10-20 13:45:49"},
{"id":"14","type":"color","value":"red","datetime":"2020-10-20 13:45:49"}
]
```

I tried many ways including following code but could not get desired result.

```
for( let prop in responce ){
console.log( responce[prop].id );
}


for( let prop in responce ){
console.log( responce[prop] );
}
```

Kindly advise how to resolve it?

Comment: yeah, because its `response` not `responce`

Comment: Already tried, no its not working

Comment: I am fetching data from MySql & return the result using PHP json_encode(). I have already posted result of console.log(responce);

Comment: I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/54403287/5558905 but got ERROR: responce.forEach is not a function

Comment: you need to give source because your code is fine

Comment: What is `typeof responce`? You might have forgotten to parse it with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: I did not parse response in ajax. I am using it directly.

Comment: ok so it's a string, not json, you need to parse it

Comment: @FlashThunder JSON *is* a string. If it is not a string, then it is not JSON.

Comment: @MyO I don't know what you mean by "using it directly". Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @str Thanx, after JSON.parse its working now. But how to access individual properties like id.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: @str Thanks, Its done !