# How to view username and password React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My json returns like this:

```
0: {username: 'silviosantos@gmail.com', password: '091591'}
1: {username: 'silviosantos@gmail.com', password: 'gkfonseca7'}
2: {username: 'silviosantos@gmail.com', password: 'oumanel'}
3: {username: 'silviosantos@gmail.com', password: 'santossilvio'}
4: {username: 'silviosantos@gmail.com', password: 'tamiratamira'}
5: {username: 'SilvioSantos@gmail.com', password: 'gkfonseca7'}
length: 6
```

[Print of response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGWOb.png)

My code:

setPasswords(response.data)
(...)
{passwords.username}

Comment: passwords[0].password and passwords[0].useername. Or [1]. Or [2]. Up to [6]. [5] will be the last. it is an array.

Comment: Are you asking "how do I iterate over the data in state to produce a table of usernames/passwords?"

Comment: don't use the image for text output try to copy and paste it or if you use an image, don't put it in the link, add it with the image option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript loop through JSON array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238173/javascript-loop-through-json-array)

Comment: add more clarity of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState({ username: '', password: '' });

...

setInfos(data); // The data you captured

return infos.map((info, index) => <>
  <span key={index}>{info.username} / {info.password}</span>
</>)
```

this code will help you